# Как добавить функцию на два элемента jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">   
                <div class="color1"></div>
                <div class="color2"></div>
                <div class="color3"></div>
                <div class="color4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="color5"></div> 
                <div class="color3"></div>
                <div class="color1"></div>
                <div class="color6"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="color7"></div>
                <div class="color6"></div>
                <div class="color8"></div>
                <div class="color5"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="color7"></div>
                <div class="color8"></div>
                <div class="color4"></div>
                <div class="color2"></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
```

```js
var firstclick
    var secondclick
        var firstclick = $(e.target).css('background-color')
        if(secondclick != null){
            secondclick = $(e.target).css('background-color')
        }
        else if(firstclick==secondclick){
        $("**те две div на которых кликали**").css("display", "none")
    }
```

Я пытаюсь создать игру *память*, только вместо картинок на картах будут рандомные цвета.

```js
    var r1=Math.floor(Math.random()*255)
    var g1=Math.floor(Math.random()*255)
    var b1=Math.floor(Math.random()*255)
    
    $(".color1").click(function (){
        $(this).css("background", "rgb(" + r1 + "," + g1 + "," + b1 + ")")
    })
```

Но не могу понять, что нужно писать чтобы дать display none тем ДВУХ div ом которые были заранее нажаты.

Comment: Если там был один элемент я бы писала $(this).css("display", "none"),то есть что писать вместо "this", если у меня 2 элементы.

Comment: Вот, добавила HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял Вы хотите скрывать элементы на которые кликнул пользователь, в этом случае стоит завести отдельную константу - массив:

```
const $array = []
```

И после каждого целевого клика заносить в нее элемент по которому пришелся клик:

```
 //... внутри eventListner'a
 $array.push(event.target)
```

в момент когда Вы посчитали что результат получен:

```
$array.css("display", "none")
// опциональная очистка массива $array = []
```

Если же Ваш вопрос просто о том как применить одно действие к нескольким элементам одновременно, то для этого можно воспользоваться методом [.add()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiR6ZLMycrqAhXDl4sKHcauAgcQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fadd%2F&usg=AOvVaw2_-qV8R_acwiHRovDXOraN):

```
const $one = $(".class-one")
const $two = $(".class-two")

const $combined = $one.add($two)
```

UPDATED:

```
let $firstClick
let $secondClick

$firstClick = $(event.target).css("background-color", "")
if ($secondClick !== null) {
    $secondClick = $(event.target).css("background-color", "")
} else if ($firstClick === $secondClick) {
    $firstClick.add($secondClick).css("display", "none")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, но и это не сработал лол :D

Comment: var firstclick
    var secondclick
    const array =[]
    function b(event){
        var firstclick = $(event.target).css('background-color')
        $(array).push(event.target)
        if(secondclick != null){
            secondclick = $(event.target).css('background-color')
        }
        else if(firstclick==secondclick){
        $(array.css("display", "none"))
    }
    }

Comment: спасибо большое :)

Comment: мне помог последний update, но там я поменяла firstclick с event.target, так как у меня в firstclick был bg-color